# Aframe light point reflect on material

Tags: shader, aframe, light, webvr

I'm using a light point in my scene. However, a weird reflection happens in the material of the objects.

The planet spins and the reflection changes depending where the light is hitting:

[image: the planet spins and the reflection changes depending where the light is hitting].

I've tried changing the roughness, the material and the shader to flat and none of them worked. Also, I'd like to have the shadows that the light point produces so that the object's geometry is evidenced, and with the ambient light this doesn't happen.

[image: object's geometry is evidenced]

How can I keep the object's shadows and not have weird reflections on?

Comment: You can perhaps reduce the material's `metalness` which causes the specular highlights. But is that a model, or a basic geometry?

Comment: I've tried that and didn't work either. They are obj models.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. The answer is in how you export your blender model. Just had to change the [specular intensity to 0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FY6pb.png), export again to obj and voilá! Problem solved. [Now it doesn't reflect the light](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q79QQ.png)